MacCluer Exercise 3.2
In MacCluer's Elementary Functional Analysis, exercise 3.2 states:
We introduce some terminology for the purpose of this problem: If $X$ is either a
real or complex vector space (meaning that the scalars used in scalar multiplication
are real, or, respectively, complex), we say that a real-valued $\phi$ is a real-linear functional if $\phi(x + y) = \phi(x)+ \phi(y)$ and $\phi(\alpha x) = \alpha\phi(x)$ holds for all $x,y \in X$ and $\alpha$
real. For $X$ a complex vector space, we say that (a complex-valued) $\phi$ is a complex linear functional if these relationships hold for all $x,y\in X$ and $\alpha$ complex.
(c) Suppose $u$ is a real-linear functional on $X$. Define $\phi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(x) =
u(x)−iu(ix)$. Show that $\phi$ is a complex-linear functional on $X$.
(d) Now suppose $X$ is a normed linear space. For $\phi$ and $u$ related as above, show
that $\vert\vert \phi \vert\vert $ = $\vert\vert u\vert\vert$.
I am confused by part d): why $\vert\vert \phi \vert\vert $ = $\vert\vert u\vert\vert$. From my understanding, since $u$ is a real valued functional, we ought to have
$$\vert\vert \phi(x)\vert\vert = \vert\vert u(x) - i u(ix)\vert \vert = \sqrt{\vert u(x)\vert^2 + \vert u(ix)\vert^2} \geq \vert u(x) \vert,$$
which means the only possible way for $\vert\vert \phi \vert\vert $ = $\vert\vert u\vert\vert$ is when $\vert\vert\phi(x)\vert\vert$ approaches $\vert\vert \phi\vert\vert$ implies $u(ix)$ approaches $0$. However, I don't see why this should be true - is there any mistake in my reasoning or any way to prove this?

I don't think this refers to the absolute values of $\phi(x)$ and $u(x)$. Note that you would not need the fact the $X$ is normed to compute those, since both the codomains are $\mathbb{C}$. In this case, the notation $|\phi|$ most likely refers to the operator norm of $\phi$, i.e., $\sup_{|x|=1} |\phi(x)|$, which does require $X$ to be normed to make sense (since we need a notion of $|x|$).

Yes, I agree - the issue is that $\vert \phi(x)\vert \geq \vert u(x)\vert$, so the operator norm of $\phi$ should also be at least the operator norm of $u$ - so I don't see how they can be equal unless they match the case I specified above.

Indeed, something seems off. For example, one could take $u$ to also be a complex functional, and then simply $\phi=2u$.

You are correct in concluding that given $x\in X$, it is not true in general that $|\phi (x)| \leq |u(x)|$. However, what can be done is that $x$ can be scaled by a complex-valued scalar $\lambda $ with absolute value $1$ such that $\phi (x) = u(\lambda x)$, from which the result follows. This is an approach worth pursuing.
To show $\|\phi\| \leq \|u\|$, let $x\in B_{X}$, where $B_{X}$ is the closed unit ball of $X$. As $\phi (x)$ is a complex number, there is some $t_{0} \in [0, 2\pi )$ such that $\phi (x) = e^{it_{0}}|\phi (x)|$. It follows that as $\phi$ is complex-linear, $\phi (e^{-it_{0}}x) = e^{-it_{0}}\phi (x) = |\phi (x)|$. As $\phi (e^{-it_{0}}x)$ is a real number, it follows that $u(e^{-it_{0}}x) = \phi (e^{-it_{0}}x)$. By using $\|e^{-it_{0}}x\| = \|x\|$, it follows that $|\phi (x)| = u(e^{-it_{0}}x) \leq \|u\|$. As this holds for all $x\in B_{X}$, it can be concluded that $\|\phi\| \leq \|u\|$.
